# How to get price for Stripe subscription product with volume pricing?

Tags: stripe-payments

How do I get the price for a subscription product in Stripe where there is volume pricing?  The [Pricing API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices?lang=node) are here.

For example, in the Stripe dashboard I create a single subscription product priced at $10/month for the first 5 units, $5 thereafter.  So if the user enters 5 into a numeric input on a webpage then I want to display $50. If the user enters 6, I want to display $30.  I want the value from Stripe, not try and calculate it in the browser.

The Stripe docs on [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview) don't seem to cover anything other than multiple tiered products, each with a fixed price.

When I create the subscription I can set the quantity, but I want to display the price before the user commits to buying.

Note: this question specifically relates to using the Stripe API and is not about getting the price by using a vendor product.

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry it wasn't clear initially.  The question specifically relates to using the API and as such, it is relevant to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Upcoming Invoice API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming) for this. In particular, you'd want to provide pricing & quantity with the `subscription_items` parameter to simulate a new subscription:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/upcoming \
  -u sk_test_123: \
  -d customer=cus_456 \
  -d 'subscription_items[0][price]=price_789' \
  -d 'subscription_items[0][quantity]=10'
```

If this is for a *new* customer, you'll need to [create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) to use with the API, as the `customer` parameter is required. You can create a customer with just a description -- it's not necessary to collect personal details up front.